# Light the darkness

Tags: knowledge, rebus, emoji

The answer is an event in Wikipedia. Find the date.

> 4️⬇️(-S)(21+A)

Comment: Is the line "an event in Wikipedia" a part of the puzzle? and if no, could you elaborate on what it means?

Comment: Might need an image version. This displays differently in desktop/mobile.